# "Show code structure in the margin" with VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

The Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio 2015 have a setting "Show code structure in the margin" (Options / Productivity Power Tools / Other Extensions) that, well, showed the code structure in the margin, at least for C# and some other languages, see this screenshot:

[image: Scrollbar map mode, left VS2015 with "Show code structure in the margin", right VS2017, both showing same C# file]

Left side is VS2015 with this option on, right is VS2017, both showing the same C# file. I’m referring to the blueish lines and half-ellipse-shaped things.

Now the [Productivity Power Tools have been refactored](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/03/06/productivity-power-tools-for-visual-studio-2017/) for Visual Studio 2017, and I wasn’t able to turn this feature on. Is it still there, and if yes, how can I turn it on?

Comment: Looks like it's being rewritten to use Roslyn instead of the old API. A C++ version is already available: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.StructureVisualizer

Comment: See also: https://github.com/Microsoft/VS-PPT/tree/master/src/Structure/StructureVisualizer

Comment: @jessehouwing I think this is the answer, thank you. If you want to post your comments as answer, I’ll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's being rewritten to use Roslyn instead of the old API. [A C++ version is already available](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.StructureVisualizer). [See also](https://github.com/Microsoft/VS-PPT/tree/master/src/Structure/StructureVisualizer).